# Red-Black-Tree delete-Method

Tags: java, red-black-tree

This delete method doesn't work:

```
public void delete(TreeNode toDelete) {
    TreeNode z = _nil;
    TreeNode x, y;

    z = toDelete.p;
    y = toDelete;
    NodeColor prevColor = y.color;
    if (z.left == _nil) {
        x = z.right;
        rbTransplant(z, z.right);
    } else if (z.right == _nil) {
        x = z.left;
        rbTransplant(z, z.left);
    } else {
        y = minimumDelete(z.right);
        prevColor = y.color;
        x = y.right;
        if (y.p == z) {
            x.p = y;
        } else {
            rbTransplant(y, y.right);
            y.right = z.right;
            y.right.p = y;
        }

        rbTransplant(z, y);
        y.left = z.left;
        y.left.p = y;
        y.color = z.color;
    }
    if (prevColor == NodeColor.BLACK) {
        correctColorsDelete(x);
    }
}

private void correctColorsDelete(TreeNode x) {
    TreeNode s;
    while (x != _root && x.color == NodeColor.BLACK) {
      if (x == x.p.left) {
        s = x.p.right;
        if (s.color == NodeColor.RED) {
          s.color = NodeColor.BLACK;
          x.p.color = NodeColor.RED;
          leftRotate(x.p);
          s = x.p.right;
        }

        if (s.left.color == NodeColor.BLACK && s.right.color == NodeColor.BLACK) {
          s.color = NodeColor.RED;
          x = x.p;
        } else {
          if (s.right.color == NodeColor.BLACK) {
            s.left.color = NodeColor.BLACK;
            s.color = NodeColor.RED;
            rightRotate(s);
            s = x.p.right;
          }

          s.color = x.p.color;
          x.p.color = NodeColor.BLACK;
          s.right.color = NodeColor.BLACK;
          leftRotate(x.p);
          x = _root;
        }
      } else {
        s = x.p.left;
        if (s.color == NodeColor.RED) {
          s.color = NodeColor.BLACK;
          x.p.color = NodeColor.RED;
          rightRotate(x.p);
          s = x.p.left;
        }

        if (s.right.color == NodeColor.BLACK && s.right.color == NodeColor.BLACK) {
          s.color = NodeColor.RED;
          x = x.p;
        } else { 
          if (s.left.color == NodeColor.BLACK) {
            s.right.color = NodeColor.BLACK;
            s.color = NodeColor.RED;
            leftRotate(s);
            s = x.p.left;
          }

          s.color = x.p.color;
          x.p.color = NodeColor.BLACK;
          s.left.color = NodeColor.BLACK;
          rightRotate(x.p);
          x = _root;
        }
      }
    }
    x.color = NodeColor.BLACK;
  }
private void rbTransplant(TreeNode u, TreeNode v) {
    if (u.p == null) {
      _root = v;
    } else if (u == u.p.left) {
      u.p.left = v;
    } else {
      u.p.right = v;
    }
    v.p = u.p;
  }

 public TreeNode minimumDelete(TreeNode node) {
        while (node.left != _nil) {
          node = node.left;
        }
        return node;
      }
```

Does anyone have an idea why so? 
I suggest the mistake is in the main delete method.
I tried adapting this: [Red-Black-Tree Implementation (ONLY DELETE!)](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/deletion-from-a-red-black-tree).

Specifically, the method head needs to be like in my code (only 1 Parameter/ TreeNode), not the key.

Thank you for your help!